# How Do I Know if the "back-sql" Option Was Compiled into OpenLDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've install openLDAP from the Ubuntu repository.

How do I know if it includes the "back-sql" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed the package, check if you have the file `/usr/lib/ldap/back_sql.so` - a simple `stat /usr/lib/ldap/back_sql.so` at the command line should show you this.

If you haven't installed the package, have a look at the [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) listings for the slapd package: e.g. the [files in the i386 slapd package for Jaunty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/i386/slapd/filelist).

Comment: Thanks! The file "back_sql.so" exists. Does that mean that MySQL support is there for sure?

Comment: Yes, if "back_sql.so" exists, MySQL support is there.

Comment: Looks like that didn't work after all. I added a sql database to slapd.conf and I get the error "Unrecognized database type (sql)".

Comment: Did you add `moduleload back_sql` to your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

One crude method is to run `ldd` on the binary `slapd` and check if it is calling any sql libraries.

Comment: Actually, this won't work as all of the SQL functionality is contained the in the back_sql.so file mentioned above.